# Overcoming GitHub API Rate-Limiting from a Public Project?

Tags: github, rate-limiting

I have a public repository which is an Ansible role. This Ansible role uses the GitHub API in order to get the most recent release for a given repository. I use this metadata in order to then subsequently download the latest release binary for the given project.

Unfortunately, I'm hitting GitHub's API rate-limit when running my tests in Travis and occasionally on my local machine. Since this is a public-facing project, what are my options for overcoming this rate limit?

I *could* use some kind of secret management system in Ansible or expose the value via Travis environment variables, but is there a standard practice for dealing with these kinds of scenarios for public code?

Answer (score 2):

Unauthenticated requests only get 60/hour. Authenticated requests get 5000/hour.

To authenticate, [generate a personal API access token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) for use by the project. Put it either in an [encrypted Travis environment variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml) or some other way to store encrypted secrets (for example, Rails has built in [encrypted credentials](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2). Use that token to access the API.

Make a separate Github account for the project and use an API token for that. This avoids sharing its rate limit with anyone else.

Use Git commands on a local clone where possible. For example, if you want to look up a commit instead of [doing it via the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/), clone the repository and use normal Git commands. Cache the clones and `git fetch` periodically to keep them up to date.

Finally, make use of [conditional requests](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#conditional-requests). These use HTTP headers so you can safely use cached queries. These do not count against your rate limit. A good Github authentication library should have an option for caching.

Comment: +1 on the 'use Git' tip, only consideration is filesystem space. I'm writing a user role, so things go in `~/.local/{share,bin}`, but downloading the repository into `~/.local/src` makes sense, fetching latest, then trying to get the latest commit. The only thing missing here is how to determine the latest tag. GitHub has a whole releases/pre-releases thing, not sure how best to do this with a regular Git repository.