# Exposing github personal access token in travis build

Tags: security, github, continuous-integration, token, travis-ci

I'm having a public repo on GitHub that validates Pull Requests on Travis by listing (and cloning) some of the organization repositories through GitHub API.

There are few options

1. Leave the pull request builder unauthorized, making it error prone to failures due GitHub API rate limits. With multiple build agents behind single IP address, and GitHub API rate limiting public calls on IP basis, this makes every 2nd or 2rd pull request build to fail. Obviously far from ideal, I need to wait for a half an hour before restarting a build
2. Set github personal access token as public/unencrypted variable (visible to the whole world) in Travis PR builds.

Now, while I know it is very bad practice to expose credentials this way (option 2), and it can be done with only "list public repos" action chosen below, what would be potential damage attacker can do aside from spending all of the API calls and again, being throttled? 
(5000/hour according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833509/overcoming-github-api-rate-limiting-from-a-public-project))

[image: github PAT actions]

Also, is there any way to overcome this limitation with different free-for-public-projects CI platform? Azure DevOps for public project seems to have same limitations (no secrets for PR builds) for security concerns.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do. Travis CI logs in with your GitHub account so you shouldn't need to set up any keys for cloning. It sounds like you have a job on Travis CI that's using the GitHub API, is that correct?

Comment: Why public? Why not set up a secret environment variable in Travis?

Comment: @DannyB secret variables are not supported for PR builds.

Comment: @Chris you are correct, PR build process uses github API to clone other repositories (not the repo that PR is raised against)